# Angular Material Icon

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mat-icon

I have installed `Angular Material` in my angular project using the command

```
ng add @angular/material
```

I have used **custom** theme, also added stylesheet in `index.html`, but when I use icon, the icon's name is visible and not the actual icon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DrawingTool</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
    />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons&display=block|Material+Icons+Outlined&display=block" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
  <body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have even tried using `Material+Icons+Outlined&display=block` in the stylesheet's href. But even that is not working.

`<mat-icon>home</mat-icon>`

[demo running on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXzJR.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.